# Can I use multiple createAsyncThunk in 1 file?

Tags: react-redux, stripe-payments, redux-toolkit

I am using react-redux, redux-toolkit, stripe for this application. After the payment has been made successfully, I want to save the order made by users and redirect them back to the homepage. Unfortunately, one line of code is not executed:

```js
    const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setProcessing(true);
        const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
            }
        });
        if (payload.error) {
            setError(`Payment failed ${payload.error.message}`);      
            setProcessing(false);
        } else {
            setError(null);
            setProcessing(false);
            setSucceeded(true);
            dispatch(postOrderToDatabase);  <--- This code seems like never run
            alert('Your payment is success, you will be redirected to the homepage');
            history.replace('/');
        };
    }
```

I think the action is not dispatched and could not be found in the action section of redux extension.

I think what could probably gone wrong is that I have 2 createAsyncThunk in one file and I think that this is why the code is being ignored.

```js
const initialState = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    address: "",
    contact: "",
    postalCode: "",
    items: [],
    totalAmount: "",
}

export const getCartItem = createAsyncThunk(
    'order/getCartItem',
    async (dispatch, {getState}) => {
      const orderedItem = getState().cartItem.cartItem
      return orderedItem;
    }
  );

export const postOrderToDatabase = createAsyncThunk(
    'order/postOrder',
    async (dispatch, {getState}) => {
        const orderDetails = getState().order;
        fetch('orders', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: orderDetails.name,
                contact: orderDetails.contact,
                email: orderDetails.email,
                address: orderDetails.address,
                postalCode: orderDetails.postalCode,
                orderedItems: orderDetails.items,
                totalAmount: orderDetails.totalAmount,
            })
        })
    }
)


const OrderDetailsSlice = createSlice({
    name: "orderDetails",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setOrderDetails: (state, action) => {
            state.name = action.payload.name
            state.email = action.payload.email
            state.address = action.payload.address
            state.contact = action.payload.contactNumber
            state.postalCode = action.payload.postalCode
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [getCartItem.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.items = action.payload
            let num = action.payload.reduce((a, c) => a + (c.cartItem.price*c.unit), 0)
            state.totalAmount = Number(num.toFixed(2))
        },
        [postOrderToDatabase.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.name = "";
            state.email = "";
            state.address = "";
            state.contact = "";
            state.postalCode = "";
            state.items = [];
            state.totalAmount = "";
        }
    }
});
```

Any idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your asyncThunk before dispatching it.

So,

```js
dispatch(postOrderToDatabase());
```

not

```js
dispatch(postOrderToDatabase);
```